# Eclipse Web Page Editor not opening JSP or HTML File

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, editor

Eclipse Version : 2020-03 (4.15.0)

So I am trying to open an HTML File in Web Page Editor for Visual Inspection of a Page as well as for building it via GUI, but it turns out to be a blank tab with no option for Design or Source whenever I am trying to open a File.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's bug [561367](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=561367), an API incompatibility introduced when modifying drag and drop behavior. You can go back to 2019-12 or update to 2020-06--the https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06 site should already contain the fix.